# Unexpected behavior when using named cell in IF condition

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365, named-ranges

I noticed something strange when using named cells in an IF condition in Excel 365 and I would like to know what's going on.

Let's say I have a named cell `MyValue`, whose value = 15.
Then, the following works fine: `=IF(MyValue > 10| "Big"| "Small")`. The cell with the formula will contain the value "Big".

However, the following causes an error to occur:
`=IF(10 < MyValue| "Big" | "Small")`

Obviously, this can easily be worked around, but it doesn't make sense to me why it should not work both ways. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Below screenshots of my workbook show the Name Manager, both versions of the formula and error resulting from "offending" formula.

[image: The working version of the formula, with Name Manager]

[image: The offending version of the formula and resulting error]

Comment: can you [edit] the post to include the name manager so we can see the formula of the named range?  I cannot reproduce your error.  I can use either formula and both return `Big` to the range.  Also let us know what error you get.

Comment: Like @ScottCraner, I am unable to reproduce your error.

Comment: Try putting a space between `MyValue` and the `|`.  The only thing I can guess is the the formula thinks that the `|` is part of the name...

Comment: Your post contains `;` but the screenshot shows `|` - why?

Answer (score 0):

Scott Craner's comment was spot-on: adding a space between `MyValue` and `|` solved it.